# How to run a 2 Jenkins agents simultaneously with only one trigger from the job on the controller

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd, jenkins-agent

I have a selenium automation project with Maven and I am currently using XML files to run the batches of test cases locally.

Now I have a requirement to run the whole suite in Jenkins, and for that, I have 2 agent EC2 instances with the project. I configured two XML files for those two agents to divide the suite among them. Now I can build them separately.

I am looking for a solution to trigger both my agents at the same time when the job on the main is being built so that I can parallely execute them with my Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Label both your instances, lets say `label1` and `label2`

then..

```
stage('Tests') {
        parallel {
            stage('Suite1') {
                steps {
                    node('label1') {
                       //do something...
                    } 
                }
            }
            stage('Suite2') {
                steps {
                    node('label2') {
                       //do something...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```